# Java Beans and Wrapper Class

Tags: java

In Java we have primitive data types and wrapper classes for them. I want to know can we use wrapper class in beans in place of primitive data types because wrapper class are final means having constant value and we can't change it. In beans we make constructor for setting values or Mutator methods .

Example

```
   Class Employee{

   private int employeeId;  //we can use Integer in place of int
   private String employeeName;
   }
```

Comment: Wrapper classes aren't going to let things be more immutable than primitive datatypes; if that's your goal there's no point.  In both cases it can be modified if and only if it's not marked `final`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, there is nothing in the JavaBeans specification that prohibits it. You just need to be aware of the trade-off you're making.

E.g., given the following class:

```
class Employee {
    private Integer employeeId;

    void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
}
```

Calling `setEmployeeId(1001)` will cause the JVM to automatically create an `Integer` wrapper object (auto-boxing). This is a cost you would avoid using primitives.

Also note that the initial value of `employeeId` will be `null`, whereas for a primite `int`, it would be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe this is OK. A bean is required to be serializable, have a zero argument constructor, and give access to its fields via getters and setters.

As long as the field types are serializable, you're good.

Comment: Notice that a quick Google search gets you to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans), which gives a clear explanation of what a bean is.